# Silverlight popup from user control to application center

Tags: silverlight, popup, center

I have a popup with a 'border' 500x500 inside of a user control... when the user clicks a button to open this popup I want the border to display in the center (horizontal/vertical) of the Application NOT the user control.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current size of your root visual and get the values.
remember, if you have control on your RootVisual, do the properly cast

```
Dim PrincipalObject = CType(Application.Current.RootVisual, System.Windows.UIElement)

Dim posY = (PrincipalObject.RenderSize.Height / 2) - (popup.Height / 2)
Dim PosX = (PrincipalObject.RenderSize.Width / 2) - (popup.Width / 2)
```

C# should be..

```
System.Windows.UIElement PrincipalObject = (System.Windows.UIElement) Application.Current.RootVisual;
Double posY = (PrincipalObject.RenderSize.Height / 2) - (popup.Height /2)
Double posX = (PrincipalObject.RenderSize.Width / 2) - (popup.Width /2)
```

Comment: Done! remember, if you have control on your RootVisual, do the properly cast